# How to do a counting of a timer configured in Mplab Harmony framework?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, mplabx, mplab-harmony

I'm new to harmony framework, and am trying to find how i can count timer iterations, so i'm doing a simple test.

I configured the timer like this:

[image]

Now i want to know if this is the correct way:

```
    uint32_t teste;
    case APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS:
    {
        while(1){
            teste = DRV_TMR0_CounterValueGet;
            printf("tmr val %d \r\n",teste);
            DRV_TMR0_CounterValueSet(0);
        }

        break;
    }
```

It happens that when i go see the print it's always the number `1660931680` doesn't make much sense to me, the timer is 16-bit so the maximum number should be somewhere near 65500.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the memory address of the `DRV_TMR0_CounterValueGet` function rather than the return value because you didn't call the function. You must call the function with `()` i.e.

`teste = DRV_TMR0_CounterValueGet();`

(not `teste = DRV_TMR0_CounterValueGet;`)

Comment: Hi @pm101 thanks it is always 0 now even after taking away DRV_TMR0_CounterValueSet(0);, do you know whats missing? i did DRV_TMR0_Start(); on APP_STATE_INIT

Comment: Ok i found what was wrong, i had timer period equal to one. I need to understand it now.